# Problem with sending message with parameter in mvvm light toolkit

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I've registered two messages:

```
  Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<DriverEventItem>>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);

Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this,NotificationMessageReceived);
```

and I have two methods to handle this message:

```
private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage<DriverEventItem> msg)
{
//something
}

private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
{
//something
}
```

but this

```
var nm=new NotificationMessage(this.SelectedShowroomLog.DriverEventItem,"ShowView2");

Messenger.Default.Send(nm);
```

invokes me the second handler.

What should I do to correctly send this driveritem to a recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply :)

NotificationMessage(this.SelectedShowroomLog.DriverEventItem,"ShowView2")